# How to add pagination in WordPress with Ajax ( I have code need debug )?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

edit:
I am creating a section in my WordPress Custom theme to show five latest titles/content from a specific category on front page template using WP_Query and also want a button to load more titles( +5 ) with the same category.

I figured it out but the issue is I want when a user refreshes the page there should be already five post present and when the user clicks to load more than it should load +5 and so on.
I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_lU7_JUS2g .

**in front-page.php**

*Section to show content*

```
<div class="col sunset-posts-container" id="displayResults"></div
```

*Load Button*

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary text-light text-center sunset-load-more" data-page="1" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">
```

**in functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_sunset_load_more', 'sunset_load_more' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sunset_load_more', 'sunset_load_more' );

function sunset_load_more() {
    $paged = $_POST['page']+1;
        // the query
        $query = new WP_Query(array(
            'category_name' => 'news',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'paged' => $paged
        ));


         if ($query->have_posts()) : 
          while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
          <p><a class="text-success" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
          <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
          </p>

             <?php endwhile; 
             wp_reset_postdata(); 
             die; 
        else : 
          __('No News');
        endif;
}
```

**in ajaxPagination.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    $(document).on('click', '.sunset-load-more', function(){

        var page = $(this).data('page');
        var ajaxurl = $(this).data('url');

        $.ajax({
            url : ajaxurl,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                page : page,
                action: 'sunset_load_more'
            },
            error : function( response ){
                console.log(response);
            },
            success : function( response ){
                $('.sunset-posts-container').append(response);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

and is it possible to make navigation instead of load more to load next five or load previews five? and when a user clicks on next, the last five will get removed ( fade out ).
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update code as below

**in front-page.php**

Section to show content

```
<div class="col sunset-posts-container" id="displayResults"></div>
```

**in functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_sunset_load_more', 'sunset_load_more' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sunset_load_more', 'sunset_load_more' );

function sunset_load_more() {
    $paged = $_POST['page']+1;
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'category_name' => 'news',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged
    ));
    if ($query->have_posts()) : 
        ob_start();
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <p><a class="text-success" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
            </p>
         <?php endwhile;
        $response   = array(
            'type'  => 'success',
            'html'  => ob_get_clean(),
            'page'  => $paged
        );
         wp_reset_postdata(); 
    else : 
      __('No News');
        $response   = array(
            'type'  => 'failure',
            'html'  =>  'No News',
        );
    endif;

    wp_send_json_success($response);
    wp_die();
}
```

**in ajaxPagination.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    $(document).on('click', '.sunset-load-more', function(){

        var page = $(this).data('page');
        var ajaxurl = $(this).data('url');

        $.ajax({
            url : ajaxurl,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                page : page,
                action: 'sunset_load_more'
            },
            error : function( response ){

            },
            success : function( response ){
                switch(response.data.type) {
                    case 'success' :
                        $('.sunset-load-more').attr('data-page',response.data.page);
                        /* you need remove last five then use html method and if you want append then use append method */
                        $('#displayResults').html(response.data.html);                        
                        break;
                    case 'failure' :
                        $('#displayResults').html(response.data.html);
                        break;
                    default :
                        break;
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Hope now you got all things and let me know still any help need.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for giving your time :) , your code is working awesome, It gives me what I want but I also want that when I reload the page there should be first five posts already present without clicking the button and then when I do click, it will load other 5. is it possible to do this? and also how to add another button to load the last 5 posts again. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes it's possible 
first five posts code you need to add before your #displayResults div. check screenshot:  http://prntscr.com/njw2zu  Also can you please accept my answer.

Comment: Okay so, when I put the code above #displayResults and when I click to load more it does not erase them and it just repeat the above one :/

Comment: Hi Chetan , are you there? Will you help me with this?

Comment: Yes please let me know if possible share site page url

Comment: Check my above comment, Please I really need help in solving this 